# Java play 2.3.9. Recover from a promise TimeoutException

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, promise

I have a function which calls the Foursquare API, and I want to set a timeout. I want to return a default value (an empty response if the timeout exceeds). My implementation:

```
public Promise<Response> getDetails(final Place place) {
    Logger.debug(BASE_URL + place.getFqId() + "?client_id=" + KEY + "&client_secret=" + SECRET_KEY + "&v=20140806&m=foursquare");

    Promise<Response> response =
    WS.url(BASE_URL + place.getFqId())
    .setQueryParameter("client_id", KEY)
    .setQueryParameter("client_secret", SECRET_KEY)
    .setQueryParameter("v", "20140806")
    .setQueryParameter("m", "foursquare")
    .setTimeout(TIMEOUT)
    .get().map(
      new Function<WSResponse, Response>() {
        public Response apply(WSResponse response) {
          JsonNode json = response.asJson();
          return new FoursquareResponse(place.getFqId(), json);
        }
      }
    );

    response.recover(new Function<Throwable, Response>() {
      public Response apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        Logger.error("error", t);
        Logger.error(place.getFqId());
        return new FoursquareResponse(place.getFqId(), null);
      }
    });

    return response;
  }
```

I set a low timeout for testing purposes (1 ms), and I'm still getting a TimeoutException, even though it enters the recover body (the error is logged).

Anyone can help? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response.recover(...)` returns a `Promise<Response>` which you do not use. I.e. you should re-assign or use the promise returned from `response.recover(...)`.

Like in this example:

`Application.java`

```
public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result timeout() throws Exception {
    int timeout = 2000;
    Thread.sleep(timeout);

    return ok(format("Just give me %d seconds!", timeout / 1000));
  }

  public static Promise<Result> takeSomeTime() throws Exception {

    return couldBeAWhile().map(new F.Function<String, Result>() {

      @Override
      public Result apply(final String body) throws Throwable {
        return ok(body);
      }
    });
  }

  public static Promise<String> couldBeAWhile() {
    Promise<WSResponse> response = WS.url("http://localhost:9000/timeout")
        .setTimeout(1000)
        .get();

  Promise<String> promise = response.map(new F.Function<WSResponse, String>() {

    @Override
    public String apply(final WSResponse wsResponse) throws Throwable {
      return wsResponse.getBody();
    }

  });

  promise = promise.recover(new F.Function<Throwable, String>() {

    public String apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
      Logger.error("Error ->", t);
      return "error";
    }
  });

  return promise;
}
```

`routes`

```
GET     /timeout                       controllers.Application.timeout()
GET     /takeSomeTime                  controllers.Application.takeSomeTime()
```

note how the `Promise` is re-assigned to `promise` and returned:

```
  ...

  promise = promise.recover(new F.Function<Throwable, String>() {

    public String apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
      Logger.error("Error ->", t);
      return "error";
    }
  });

  return promise;
```

In the above example, if you hit http://localhost:9000/takeSomeTime, you will get a response of 'error' back after the timeout is triggered.

So in your case, you could probably change your method to the following and it should work as expected:

```
public Promise<Response> getDetails(final Place place) {
    Logger.debug(BASE_URL + place.getFqId() + "?client_id=" + KEY + "&client_secret=" + SECRET_KEY + "&v=20140806&m=foursquare");

    Promise<Response> response =
    WS.url(BASE_URL + place.getFqId())
    .setQueryParameter("client_id", KEY)
    .setQueryParameter("client_secret", SECRET_KEY)
    .setQueryParameter("v", "20140806")
    .setQueryParameter("m", "foursquare")
    .setTimeout(TIMEOUT)
    .get().map(
      new Function<WSResponse, Response>() {
        public Response apply(WSResponse response) {
          JsonNode json = response.asJson();
          return new FoursquareResponse(place.getFqId(), json);
        }
      }
    ).recover(new Function<Throwable, Response>() {
      public Response apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        Logger.error("error", t);
        Logger.error(place.getFqId());
        return new FoursquareResponse(place.getFqId(), null);
      }
    });

    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related with your recover definition. It should be something like:

```
response.recover{
  case ex: Throwable => new Function<Throwable, Response>() {
    public Response apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
      Logger.error("error", t);
      Logger.error(place.getFqId());
      return new FoursquareResponse(place.getFqId(), null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is Java 8? How can I write the same thing in Java 6

Comment: @ssuljic This is not Java 8, it's the Scala syntax. See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS#Common-Patterns-and-Use-Cases).